# gem TweetStream change user_ids dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, tweetstream

How after this code change user_ids dynamically?

```
TweetStream::Client.new.follow(14252, 53235) do |status|
    puts "#{status.text}"
end
```

For example I start TweetStream with user_ids from DB, but after that I have a new one user_id. How add a new user_id to the follow array?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

before you need to make your code more flexible

```
client = TweetStream::Client.new
```

next

```
client.sitestream(['115192457'], :followings => true) do |status|
  puts status.inspect
end
```

and do something like this:

```
client.control.add_user('2039761')
client.control.remove_user('115192457')
```

but you will need to use Eventmachine or something else for this code